# Java/JDK filesystem organization on OSX (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, java, jdk

If you install the JDK via the Oracle DMG, you get content put under

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_xx/Content/Home/bin
```

as well as

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/
```

There is basically a full duplication of binaries in these two directories and they aren't sym/hard links to each other.  In the latter case, the Current dir is a symlink to the A dir at the same level.  However, this doesn't explain how this is relevant to the former directory  (`/Libraray/Java/...`).

`/usr/bin/java*` is/are symlinked to the binaries in the `/System/Library/Frameworks/`.... directory.

Is there some rhyme to the reason why this is how Java is organized in OSX?

So another observation:

> > /usr/libexec/java_home

generates:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So while the `/usr/bin/java` executable points to the `/System/Library/Framework/....` location, the java_home script generates a path to the Home directory in the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/...`

This is a mess quite frankly - why is this so?

Comment: So doing some digging, and I think I have a hunch that the executables that /usr/bin/java* point to in the /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/ directory are just wrapper binaries that use /usr/libexec/java_home to find the true java binaries.  Can anyone corroborate this?

Comment: Anyone?  I can't be the only one who is wondering about this?